# Google+ Sign in error in android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, google-identity

I'm trying to add Google+ sign in button to my android app, and I moved step by step on what written here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in
and here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

But no matter what I did, the sign-in process always failed and the error that I get is "UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE" (17).

The onConnected function never called, just the onConnectionFailed.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code where you build the `GoogleApiClient`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try checking whether it's your code and not the console configuration by getting the [Google Sign-in Android Quickstart sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android) app working.

Make sure that you have [configured your developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) to have a developer email setup as described in [step 4 of part 1 of the Android getting started instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_sign-in_api).

Update:

Double, triple, and quadruple check that you have selected an email from the consent screen:

---

[image]

Even if you have one email address, you must select an email address and configure the consent screen or else you will get this one weird code.

99% of the time, these issues are caused by misconfiguration of the Google API console, so you might want to try using the new json-based configuration described at https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: Like I said, I write exactly what written in the android instructions.